# Issues running my Tensorflow model on GPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm new to Tensorflow. I have a Tensorflow code which is running on CPU, but I'm trying to change it to run on GPU. I added the `tf.device('/device:GPU:0')` statement somewhere, but apparently it doesn't work, and I don't see a log.

How to change it?

```
#...some stuff
g_in = tf.Graph()
with gfile.FastGFile(path + name + '.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
    g_in = tf.get_default_graph()
    print(g_in)

with g_in.as_default(), tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
    input = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("cnn/input_1:0")
    output = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("mymodel:0")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow will run on the GPU by default if you have `tensorflow-gpu` installed.
 `with tf.device('/device:GPU:0')` is used to choose which GPU to use if you do not want to run it on the default.
`pip freeze` should show you which installation you have. If it only says `tensorflow` and not `tensorflow-gpu` then you need to uninstall it, install CUDA and reinstall `tensorflow-gpu`